# Gradient Border Color Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to place a gradient on the border of a frame but I get this error:
"Property BorderColor does not support values of type "GradientStop"
Before this, I tryed in a button and guess what... the same error.
Code:
`

```
<Frame WidthRequest="300"
        HeightRequest="50"
        CornerRadius="20"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Grid.Row="4"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        Margin="0,50,0,50"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent">
    <Frame.BorderColor>
        <GradientStop Color="#3C95E8" Offset="0.1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#DD7777" Offset="0.5" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FFC455" Offset="1.0" />
    </Frame.BorderColor>
    <Label TextColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">Continuar</Label>
    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnContinue}"/>
    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
</Frame>
```

`
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I already find solution, I hope help anybody. Just use PancakeView.

```
        <Frame WidthRequest="300"
    HeightRequest="50"
    CornerRadius="20"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
    Grid.Row="4"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    Margin="0,50,0,50"
    BackgroundColor="Transparent">

    <yummy:PancakeView
        CornerRadius="20">
        <Label TextColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">Continuar</Label>
        <yummy:PancakeView.Border>
            <yummy:Border Thickness="2">
                <yummy:Border.GradientStops>
                    <yummy:GradientStopCollection>
                        <yummy:GradientStop Color="#3C95E8" Offset="0.1"/>
                        <yummy:GradientStop Color="#DD7777" Offset="0.5"/>
                        <yummy:GradientStop Color="#FFC455" Offset="1.0"/>
                    </yummy:GradientStopCollection>
                </yummy:Border.GradientStops>
            </yummy:Border>
        </yummy:PancakeView.Border>
    </yummy:PancakeView>

    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnContinue}"/>
    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
</Frame>
```